# Opening files from iPad in Excel?

Tags: ios, windows, ipad, itunes

I have an iPad app that creates XML files and saves them to the iPad's Documents Directory.  I would like to get these files to excel, but I am fairly certain I cannot just launch excel > open > then navigate through the iPads directory.

What's the best way to get these files?  Are there any windows applications that allow you to access the iPad's directories ?  Or will I have to use iTunes ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out "CloudOn":

- [Excel on my iPad](http://blogs.computerworld.com/20102/excel_on_my_ipad_free)
- http://site.cloudon.com/

Comment: those are neat, but I am not looking to edit/open the documents on the iPad.  They are just created on the device, and then opened on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

For your needs, I have the habit of going through the Beesy application: http://www.beesapps.com/management-productivity/import-excel-files-on-ipad/. I can import/export such a file in my iPad and if I need to make changes, I can make notes in the margins of the doc to complete thereafter.